# SQL update query

Tags: sql

I want to update two fields in one sql query. How do I do that?

`update tablename set field1= val1 where id=1`

Now I want to update 2 fields as follows: How can I do that?

`update tablename set field1 =val1 and set field2=val2 where id=1`

Comment: Did we help you?  You should mark an answer as correct if we did.

Answer (score 18):

Your syntax is almost correct, but you can't use AND.

```
UPDATE tablename SET field1=var1, field2=var2 WHERE id=1
```

Answer (score 4):

Or to be safe, I like to write UPDATE statements like this:

```
UPDATE T
SET
    T.Field1 = Value1
    ,T.Field2 = Value2
-- SELECT *
FROM TableName AS T
WHERE T.ID = 1
```

This way you can be sure of what you'll be updating.

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it:

```
update tablename 
set field1=val1,
field2=val2 
where id=1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE  TableName
SET     Field1=Value1
       ,Field2=Value2
WHERE   id=id_value
```

Like the others, but this is how I like to indent and format it, on bigger complex queries, proper formating matters alot!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE tablename SET field1 = var1, field2 = var2 WHERE id = 1;

COMMIT;